# The term 'Set-AzureKeyVaultKeyAttributes' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-keyvault

On my `Windows 10` I've `Powershell 5.0` installed. But when I run the following command on it, I get the above error.

**PS command:**

```
Set-AzureKeyVaultKeyAttributes -Name Key2 -VaultName KayVault-abctest -Enable $false
```

**Error**

> Set-AzureKeyVaultKeyAttributes : The term 'Set-AzureKeyVaultKeyAttributes' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
>   path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-AzureKeyVaultKeyAttributes -Name Key2 -VaultName KayVault-abctest ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureKeyVaultKeyAttributes:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

**Note**
I'm using the topic `Create a Key (Portal)` in this [official Azure lab](https://prod-edxapp.edx-cdn.org/assets/courseware/v1/437c58512b966d5863367fc0555b857d/asset-v1:Microsoft+AZURE208x+4T2017+type@asset+block/Module_2_Key_Vault_Practical_Exercises.pdf) tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the name of the cmdlet should be the singular [`Set-AzureKeyVaultKeyAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/set-azurekeyvaultkeyattribute?view=azurermps-5.0.0), rather than the plural `Set-AzureKeyVaultKeyAttributes`. Note that this is one of the [Strongly Encouraged Development Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878270(v=vs.85).aspx) for Powershell by Microsoft:

> To enhance the user experience, the noun that you choose for a cmdlet name should be singular. For example, use the name Get-Process instead of Get-Processes. It is best to follow this rule for all cmdlet names, even when a cmdlet is likely to act upon more than one item.

If you are still seeing the same problem while using a singular name, ensure that the [AzureRM.KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/?view=azurermps-5.0.0) module is installed and loaded:

```
Install-Module AzureRM.KeyVault
Import-Module AzureRM.KeyVault
```

Comment: You were 100% correct. It worked when I used singular (removed 's' at the end) - thank you. Your reference from Microsoft's guideline on Powershell was also of great help as I would (or at least should) remember that.